# Individual animation events for div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, animation

How do I set individual animation events for the `<div>` tag?

In my case event for `div#1` and `div#2` (both individual events) are activated at the same time, which isn't what I want.

After the `div.page` moves on the left it has to become green (10 seconds)

After the `div.subpage` falls down it has to become black (3 seconds)

Instead of it both blocks are painted at once (3 seconds)

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/hpmdh8k1/

```
<html>

<head>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<style>

.page {
    display:            block;

    position:           absolute;
    left:               200px;
    top:                100px;

    width:              200px;
    height:             500px;

    text-align:         center;
    color:              #ffffff;

    background-color:   #bb0000;
}

.page-anim {
    animation:              moveRightPrevious 10.0s ease both;
        -webkit-animation:  moveRightPrevious 10.0s ease both;  
}

@keyframes moveRightPrevious {
    from    { transform: translateX(0%); }
    to      { transform: translateX(500%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveRightPrevious {
    from    { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateX(500%); }
}

.subpage {
    display:            block;

    position:           absolute;
    left:               50px;
    top:                50px;

    width:              100px;
    height:             100px;

    background-color:   #bbbb00;
}

.subpage-anim {
    animation:              moveBottomPrevious 3.0s ease both;
        -webkit-animation:  moveBottomPrevious 3.0s ease both;  
}

@keyframes moveBottomPrevious {
    from    { transform: translateY(0%); }
    to      { transform: translateY(300%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveBottomPrevious {
    from    { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateY(300%); }
}

#green {
    background-color:   #00bb00;
}

#black {
    background-color:   #000000;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class = "page">
<div class = "subpage"></div>
click anywhere
</div>

<script>

    $(window).click(function(){

        var pageUnit = $(".page");
        pageUnit.data('originalClassList', pageUnit.attr('class'));

        var subpageUnit = $(".subpage");
        subpageUnit.data('originalClassList', subpageUnit.attr('class'));

        pageUnit.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function()
        {
            pageUnit.off('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend');

            pageUnit.attr('id', 'green');
        });

        subpageUnit.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function()
        {
            subpageUnit.off('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend');

            subpageUnit.attr('id', 'black');        
        }); 

        pageUnit.attr('class', pageUnit.data('originalClassList') + ' page-anim');
        subpageUnit.attr('class', subpageUnit.data('originalClassList') + ' subpage-anim'); 
    });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please show your attempts in a MVCE with jsfiddle or similar

Comment: already :) my torment with links and code on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments, what's happening is that the animation events are being bubbled up to the containing div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation

http://jsfiddle.net/pqxqL1L0/

So as you can see in the fiddle, I've passed the event through as `e`, and then on the `subPage` event function, we call `e.stopPropagation();`.

This stops it then getting called for the parent container which also has listeners for the same events.

Comment: no, 
Animations have to be started at the same time (0sec)
The small (child) block will finish the movement by the first and has to be painted in black color (3sec)
The big block will finish the movement by the second and has to be painted in green color (10sec)

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: ok, in this case e.stopPropagation() works.
Now, more difficult case (my) 
http://jsfiddle.net/h0wg0j3y/
1] to wait for animation (2sec), 2] click button "click here", 3] to wait more 3 seconds 4] click button "click here", ... -> and now corrupted vertical animation :(. Why!!!!? I thought that a problem in $().on('animationend'), but I was mistaken

Answer (score 1):

Please find the attached link,

http://jsfiddle.net/hpmdh8k1/2/

Source:

```
$(window).click(function(){

    var pageUnit = $(".page");
    pageUnit.data('originalClassList', pageUnit.attr('class'));

    var subpageUnit = $(".subpage");
    subpageUnit.data('originalClassList', subpageUnit.attr('class'));

    pageUnit.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function()
    {
        pageUnit.off('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend');

        pageUnit.attr('id', 'green');
  subpageUnit.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function()
    {
        subpageUnit.off('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend');

        subpageUnit.attr('id', 'black');        
    });
subpageUnit.attr('class', subpageUnit.data('originalClassList') + ' subpage-anim'); 
    });

    pageUnit.attr('class', pageUnit.data('originalClassList') + ' page-anim');

});
```

Comment: your example shows synchronous  (consecutive) animation
but asynchronous  (parallel) animation is necessary

Comment: You can use setTimeout function. please refer the link below, hope it helps you.                                                                                             http://jsfiddle.net/hpmdh8k1/3/

Comment: setTimeout - it not a universal way :(
time of animation can change, and it means that I should change also timeout